# Lightning Knowledge has no related list for article version history

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I want to add history (knowledgearticleversionhistory) related list on knowledge article version layout as related list but it is not available. I can query it through SOQL. Do we have any out of the box solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an article version component in your lightning page like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it kind of solved the problem but not user friendly as versions and article history should be seperated and not grouped together